# how to attach ssrs report to an email in D365fo

Tags: reporting-services, email-attachments, x++, erp, dynamics-365-operations

so I am looking for an approach to attach an SSRS report (in pdf format) to an email once a batch job gets completed. I want the report to get attached to the email without downloading the pdf report. someone  suggested to look up report reference but couldn't find anything

Comment: Trigger a subscription to the report when the batch job completes perhaps?

Comment: You can use a URL request to extract the PDF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16. What triggers this "batch job"? Is it SQL Server? Do you have sql mail set up? Is this a completely on-premises set up or is it cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the PDF generated by SSRS is temporarily stored on the built-in Blob Storage of D365. This Blob storage is not directly accessible, so sharing a link to a customer via e-mail is not the recommended solution. I believe the solution directions are either to download the PDF to be able to attach it to the e-mail, or copy the PDF from the built-in Blob storage towards another Blob Storage (or SharePoint 365) and share the link in the e-mail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: An on prem installation of SSRS will definitely not be doing this. Power BI "Paginated" reports might do this